# Помогите составить запрос к БД!

Tags: php, mysql

Есть Таблица messages и поля:
id - ID сообщения
author - Автор сообщения
poluchatel - Получатель сообщения
text - Текст сообщения

Есть 4 сообщения:

id - 1
author - Коля
poluchatel - Юля
text - Привет Юля!

id - 2
author - Петя
poluchatel - Юля
text - Привет Юля!

id - 3
author - Петя
poluchatel - Юля
text - Привет Юля!

id - 4
author - Вася
poluchatel - Юля
text - Как дела?

Мне нужно вывести все сообщения, где (poluchatel - Юля), всех авторов, которые отправили ей сообщение, и только по одному последнему их сообщении!
Вот какие сообщения должны вывестись:

id - 1
author - Коля
poluchatel - Юля
text - Привет Юля!

id - 3
author - Петя
poluchatel - Юля
text - Привет Юля!

id - 4
author - Вася
poluchatel - Юля
text - Как дела?

Comment: C выводом решил проблему, ещё один вопрос, делаю подсчет количества сообщений при выводе (те же 3 сообщения)

Вод код:
$result_messages = mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE poluchatel='Юля' GROUP BY 'author'",$db);
$sum_messages = mysql_fetch_array($result_messages);

echo "У ВАС $sum_messages[0] СООБЩЕНИЙ"; 

только при таком запросе выдает количество всех подсчитанных сообщений которые отправляли Юле, а мне нужно подсчитать количество как в запросе выше!) При выходе должно быть так:
У ВАС 3 СООБЩЕНИЯ, то есть сообщение (id-1 id-3 id-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запрос ведь простейший... И почему-то у меня ощущение, что мой ответ - это только начало обсуждения. У вас начнут всплывать всякие "но", "а если" и т.д.

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `poluchatel` = 'Юля' GROUP BY `author` ORDER BY `id`
```

Comment: Извините, немного ошибся с кодом, вместо id - 2 author - Петя poluchatel - Юля text - Привет Юля! должно быть id - 2 author - Вася poluchatel - Юля text - Привет Юля!

Comment: если я напишу таков запрос SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `poluchatel` = 'Юля' GROUP BY `author` ORDER BY `id`
мне с базы вытащить первые сообщения всех авторов, а мне нужно последние сообщения всех авторов! то есть Вася написал 2 сообщения, а при выходе выводит его сообщение id - 4, а при таком запросе мне выведит id - 2

Answer (score 1):

**Учите SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver = 'name' GROUP BY author ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: DESC ставится для того чтобы сортировка производилась в обратном порядке!

Comment: С подсчетом решил вопрос, ещё последний вопрос, как удалить сообщения например: вот код 
DELETE FROM  `messages` WHERE author=`Вася`

Как удалить все сообщения у Юле, которые отправил Вася, то есть как удалить сразу 2 сообщения, это можно сделать через LIMIT (DELETE FROM  `messages` WHERE author=`Вася` LIMIT 2), а если LIMIT - неизвестно ?

Comment: DELETE FROM messages WHERE author = 'Вася' AND receiver = 'Юля'